# c++ how to free memory *char?

Tags: c++, memory, char, free

How to free memory with something like this (Visual Studio 2008 - Win32/console):

I can include only: iostream

```
#include <iostream>

void data_t(char *test[])
{
    test[0] = new char[];
    test[1] = new char[];
    test[0] = "Test1";
    test[1] = "Test2";
}

int main()
{
    char *test[2];
    data_t(test);
    cout<<test[0]<<"\n";
    cout<<test[1]<<"\n";
    delete[] test[0];//Debug assertion failed! - The program '[7884] Zadanie_4_sortowanie.exe: Native' has exited with code 3 (0x3).
    delete[] test[1];
}
```

What i do wrong?

Comment: What is `new char[]` intended to mean? It is not legal C++.

Comment: It's sad that MSVS accepts this sort of thing. I wonder what it does with it?

Comment: The assigment operator on character pointers does not copy data, it just changes it just assigns the pointer. So, assuming you fixed `new[]`s to be, say, `new[6]` so that those two lines worked you immediately leak that memory by redirecting both pointers to point to string literals. The error occurs because you can only `delete[]` something that you allocated with `new[]` and those pointers currently point to the literals. Short version, use `std:string` if you can and understand c string manipulation if you must use null terminated character buffers.

Comment: Im sure the array index is a typo. YOU CAN'T FREE STRING LITERALS. AHHHH. MUST... USE.... STRCPY... TO MAKE... PROFESSOR... FEEL... GOOD.. ABOUT BEING... SO.. OLD...AS... TO ... KNOW.....     C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "Test1" and "Test2" are used by your program at runtime (they are printed by cout), the compiler has to save them somewhere. It does this by putting them both into your executable.

Since they are both in your executable already, there is no reason to allocate any new memory. 
So you can remove the first two lines in data_t.

If you do this you will get a compiler error, though this error should have already been there, which will complain that you are trying to assign a string literal ("Test1", "Test2") to a non const array.

The problem here is that strings saved by the compiler into the executable are NOT to be modified. You are only printing them, but data_t doesn't know that. To fix the problem you should use `const char *` instead of `char *`

If you intend to modify these strings, you'll need to allocate new memory and copy the strings into it.

Answer (score 5):

`char[]` is an incomplete type, and cannot be used in a `new` expression. You need to actually decide on an array size, like:

```
char * p = new char[200];
```

Then you can say `delete[] p;` when you're done.

You will need something like `strcpy` to copy data *into* the `char` array. The assigment you wrote only overwrites the pointer, thus losing track of the dynamic allocation (i.e. leaking). (In fact, you might not need dynamic allocation at all if you just want fixed strings, so just remove the lines with `new` and `delete` in them.)

---

What you really want, though, is a `std::array<std::string, 2>`, though:

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::array<std::string, 2> test =  { "Test1", "Test2" };
std::cout << test[0] << "\n" << test[1] << "\n";
```

Or pass it by reference:

```
void populate(std::array<std::string, 2> & a)
{
    a[0] = "Test1";
    a[1] = "Test2";
}

int main()
{
    std::array<std::string, 2> test;
    populate(test);
    // print ...
}
```

Comment: I would also mention that `data_t()` leaks memory, and doing `delete[] p` on a string literal is likely to cause troubles

Comment: But i need to free memory ? i have memory leak with that code?

Comment: @wcale: Your code shouldn't even compile... But yes, you would be leaking memory if this worked, because you're losing the pointer returned by the `new` expression.

Comment: @wcale: When you will fix your code to make it compile (by adding a concrete size to `new char[]`), you will get a memory leak, because when doing `test[0] = "Test1"` and `test[1]="Test2"` you are reassigning `test[0]` and `test[1]` without releasing the memory they previously pointed to. And then when doing `delete test[0]` you will be trying to deallocate a string literal, which is Undefined Behavior. Same for `delete test[1]`.

Comment: teacher of my girlfriend says that " it can be used only "iostream" - this is database with quicksort... btw code above compiled very well, but in debug mode i have error. And this memory leak. This is my last part of this application.

Comment: `int main()
{
    cout<< "Test1\n";
    cout<< "Test2\n";
}`

Comment: @dmckee: Erm, I asked, why is the OP restricted to using `<iostream>`.

Comment: @dmckee: No problem! You should have kept your comment; it was, despite being misdirected, completely accurate.

Answer (score 5):

test[0] contains a pointer to the static string "Test1", which cannot be deallocated. Use strcpy to copy C strings.

Comment: Yes. The real issue. Considering the code is claimed to complie, the issue of neglecting the size of the array is probably a typo.